# Array in JS only running last value for variance

Tags: javascript, arrays, variance

I know something is horribly wrong. I am trying to do a variance function with an array 10,20,30-100. But it runs through all the values like 10,20 but only displays the value for 100. So the end result is `100-avg^2/N`. How do I get the function to `(value)-avg^2` and then sum all the values before `/N`.

```js
function varp(array) {
    var i, varps
    N = array.length
    for (i=0;i<N;i=i+1) {
       varps=((array[i]-avg)**2)/N
       }
    return varps
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable varps only contains one value. You're overwriting the previous value every time you run the loop. If you want to add the result of the current loop to some aggreagator, instantiate that variable outside of the loop then add the value to it instead of re-assigning it:

```
function varp(array) {
    let i, total;
    const len = array.length

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        total += ((array[i] - avg) ** 2) / len
    }
    return total
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually tried to use += before and got NaN. Sadly I still get that.

Comment: What array are you passing in? You may want to review data types in JavaScript. If you're passing in an array that doesn't contain numbers (or if your avg is not a number), then it won't be able to perform the operation like you expect. As a hint, a number should NOT be wrapped in quotes. Technically speaking, `2` is a number, but `"2"` is a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Comment: Yeah the array are numbers not a string, as avg is computed with an above function that sums all of the values in the array to 550 and divides by 10 the array.length

Comment: Ok, so setting total = 0 fixed it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah good catch, that would have hemmed me up for a while. Good job!